# Likert vs Non-Likert Data

Tags: data-visualization, likert

I have several types of data from a recent experiment:

1. Integer-quantized subject test scores from 0 to 30 (gathered with and without the use of an experimental tool)
2. Floating point subject response (data about how they were using a tool)
3. 7-point Likert data (data about their opinions of the tool)

The particulars of the data have me interested in comparing, visualizing, and perhaps analyzing some of the Likert data vs the other two types of data, especially the integer-quantized data.

The only thought I have so far is a scatter plot (test scores on vertical, Likert on horizontal) and perhaps a linear regression.  But after a few hours of searching, and somewhat to my surprise, I can find no examples of plots of Likert vs non-Likert data.

Are there any analysis techniques ***or*** visualization techniques that are helpful, here?

Comment: Likert type data can be translated into continuous data by use of scoring system. You can do different types of statistical analysis.

Comment: @SubhashC.Davar I'm not sure I understand what you mean by scoring system.  Is this something that can be done after the fact, or is this something I would have to design into the study before it's start?

Comment: It is after the data has been collected.

Comment: Have you [looked at the relevant posts here on CV?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=likert+data+plot+score%3A2)  One of the higher-voted hits appears at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25109/visualizing-likert-responses-using-r-or-spss/25156#25156.